# Oracle export: table doesn't exist

Tags: oracle

I am trying to export data in oracle 11g

```
exp user/password file=dump.dmp tables = (table1)
```

via sqlplus.

And i get the following error:

> About to export specified tables via Conventional Path ...
>   EXP-00011: USER.TABLE1 does not exist
>  Export terminated
>   successfully with warnings.

But when i check who is the owner of this table:

```
SELECT owner, table_name from dba_tables where table_name = 'TABLE1';
```

I get that the owner of `TABLE1` is `USER`

What should i do to export this table?

### UPDATE

Actually, i found a solution. I hope it will help someone else.
Since version 11g Oracle has introduced new feature that is called deferred segment creation. Thus oracle doesn't create table segment if there are now rows in it. So i recreated my table with option 'segment creation immediate'

Comment: did u try: tables=user.table1

Comment: Do: `exp user/password@DBNAME file=dump.dmp tables=(table1)` to make sure you're connecting to the correct database.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't help. Actually, maybe i should have mentioned that i have a lot of tables in schema and when i'm trying to export some other tables, everything is okay.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue.  Can you read data from this table, as in `SELECT * FROM USER.TABLE1` when logged in with the same user and password used in the `exp` command?

Comment: Yes, i can. Actually there is no data, but i can get access.

Comment: There was the only difference between tables that i can and i cant export. This block:  'storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );' But i recreated my non-exporting table with this block but it hasn't helped

Comment: Can you add the solution you've found as an answer ? latter on mark it as an "accepted answer"

Comment: for sure, when i will be allowed to do it (in 4 hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, i found a solution. I hope it will help someone else. Since version 11g Oracle has introduced new feature that is called deferred segment creation. Thus oracle doesn't create table segment if there are no rows in it. And my table didn't contain any data. So i recreated my table with option 'segment creation immediate'

The solution was found [here](http://oracletube.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/oracle-11gr2-exp-00011-occurs-even-object-exist-in-schema/). There are more options how to fix the problem and an explanation why this thing happens to be in oracle 11g. :)

Comment: Oh good job, thanks for the feedback on that then. In 11g though I'd definitely look at using datapump as an alternative to exp/imp, particularly when 10g+ features are in use. There's a learning curve in there of course and in some ways it's less convenient (needing a directory object for example) but if you follow the usual principle of "get a script that works then modify it for future needs" then you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the posted answer from Olivia i would like to add some code:

```
SELECT 'alter table ' ||  table_name || ' allocate extent;'
from dba_tables where SEGMENT_CREATED = 'NO';
```

Execute the output and exp again. Your schema will be exported including empty tables.

EDIT:
similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924704/how-to-export-empty-tables-in-oracle/22859017#22859017), maybe you'll find your solution there.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
exp user/password file=dump.dmp tables = (table1);
```

to this:

```
exp user/password tables = (table1) file=dump.dmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use below query to take table level export from specific user.

```
exp user/password file=dump.dmp tables = user.table1
```